# TypeError: 'NoneType' en Python Flask

Tags: python, json, post, flask

Mi version de `Python 3.7.4`

Por medio de *Ajax* obtengo el siguiente dicionario:

```
[{'DiaTur': '2020-03-13', 'IdPacPlan': '2', 'HorTur': '09:10', 'HorFtur': '09:45', 'IdEsp': '19', 'IdProf': ''}]
```

Por medio de Flask quiero ingresar a los id y valore de ese diccionario de la siguiente manera:

```
@app.route("/probando", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def probando():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.get_json()
        #print(data)

        DiaTur=data['DiaTur']
        IdPacPlan=data['IdPacPlan']
        HorTur=data['HorTur']
        HorFtur=data['HorFtur']
        IdEsp=data['IdEsp']
        IdProf=data['IdProf']
        print(DiaTur,IdPacPlan,HorTur,HorFtur,IdEsp,IdProf) 
        return redirect (url_for("index"))
```

Pero me tira un error

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Como puedo solucionarlo

Comment: Supongo que te lo genera la linea `DiaTur=data['DiaTur']`, en ese caso `request.get_json()` (`data`) te está retornando `None` y esto pasa en principio porque el cliente no indica que está enviando un JSON en las cabeceras de la respuesta ([mimetype](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_Types)).

Comment: Puede ser, me llama la atencion que en otro codigo lo tengo similar, solo cambian los datos, y me funciona, nunca me paso. Gracias igual

Comment: El inconveniente lo tuve en que el button era de tipo submit, y enviaba un formulario por JS puro, lo que es imposible, y a su vez una funcion .click() ejecutava el envio por Jquery, cambie el tipo de boton y solucionado el inconveniente. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El error ocurre porque `data` es `None` y al hacer `data['DiaTur']` tenemos el mencionado error porque obviamente `None` no es un contenedor.

La razón de que `request.get_json()` retorne `None` la tenemos en principio en la [documentación](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=get_json#flask.Request.get_json) (traducción libre):

> Si el tipo MIME no indica JSON (`application/json`, ver `is_json()`), el método retorna `None`.

Podrías hacer que flask ignore los tipos MIME usando el parámetro `force` con valor `True`, esto indica que se trate siempre de parsear la respuesta como JSON:

```
data = request.get_json(force=True)
```

No obstante no deberías usar la solución anterior, sino que deberías hacer que el cliente indique de forma correcta el tipo MIME como `'application/json'`.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/probando',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        ...
    });
```